# Type 'number' is not assignable to type '(...items: any[]) => number'

Tags: angular

I am doing an online course in Angular i know nothing about programming
I can't find a solution to my problem what is wrong and where should i even look for my mistake
I am using no strict mode

My html code:

```
<button
  class="btn btn-primary"
  (click)="onToggleDetails()">Display details</button>
<p *ngIf="showSecret">Secret password = tuna</p>
<div *ngFor="let logAmount of log">{{ logItem }}</div>
```

My ts code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  showSecret = false;
  log = [];

  onToggleDetails() {
    this.showSecret = !this.showSecret;
    this.log.push = (this.log.length + 1)
  }
}
```

Any help and explanation would be appreciated !

Comment: What are try to do with using the `onToggleDetails` function.

Answer (score 2):

Will try to make this answer as simple as possible.
The problem is the way you are using the array's `push` function incorrectly.
Below code of your's

```
onToggleDetails() {
    this.showSecret = !this.showSecret;
    this.log.push = (this.log.length + 1)
  }
```

Is trying to assign a number to the function `push` which is not allowed, hence the error.

Try the below code instead it will solve this error. `.push` is a function that takes a parameter(s) when called. Below is how you call it.

```
onToggleDetails() {
    this.showSecret = !this.showSecret;
    this.log.push(this.log.length + 1);
  }
```

To read more refer this [array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Answer (score 1):

`.htmlFile`

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onToggleDetails()">
  Display details
</button>
<p *ngIf="showSecret">Secret password = tuna</p>
<div *ngFor="let logAmount of log">{{ logAmount }}</div>
```

`.tsFile`

```
showSecret = false;
  log = [];

  onToggleDetails() {
    this.showSecret = !this.showSecret;
    let data = this.log.length + 1;
    this.log.push(data);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

log = [];
try these you can solve these problem by  log: number[] = [];

Comment: please format your answer and explain how it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).